# Invoke operation 'myMethod' failed in RIA Services in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, ria

I have a server-side WCF RIA Service that is intentionally throwing an exception because the user entered an invalid value. This exception comes across the wire, however, I can't figure out how to catch it. I currently have the following code:

```
try
{
  DomainContext.CalculateRequest(OnCalculateCompleted, null);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show("here");
}

...

private void OnCalculateCompleted(InvokeOperation response)
{
  try
  {
    if (response.HasError == false)
    {
      // Do stuff with result
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

How do I handle exceptions thrown by a server-side operation on the client side? None of my catch statements are being triggered. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client side the `InvokeOperation.HasErrors` will be `true` and you can get the Exception object from the `InvokeOperation.Error`. Note, if you handled the error you should also call `MarkErrorAsHandled()`.

Your OnCalculateCompleted might looks something like this.

```
private void OnCalculateCompleted(InvokeOperation response)
{
  if (response.HasError == false)
  {
    // Do stuff with result
  }
  else
  {
    MessageBox.Show(response.Error.Message);
    response.MarkErrorAsHandled();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because in the callback (OnCalculateCompleted), exception will not be marshalled. The exception will reside in the response.Error property.

But take care, because your server-side thrown exception will NOT be found in the response.Error!

You should override your DomainService's OnError method, package your server-side exception via errorcodes or something, and on the client (SL) side, you have to unpack it again.